# Failed to compile shader in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, opengl-es, swift, shader

The CameraViewController.swift class code given below.

```
//
//  CameraViewController.swift
//  iOSSwiftOpenGLCamera
//
//  Created by Bradley Griffith on 7/3/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Bradley Griffith. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import CoreMedia
import AVFoundation

class CameraViewController: UIViewController, CameraSessionControllerDelegate {

    var cameraSessionController: CameraSessionController!
    @IBOutlet var openGLView: OpenGLView!
    @IBOutlet var togglerSwitch: UISwitch!


    /* Lifecycle
    ------------------------------------------*/

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        cameraSessionController = CameraSessionController()
        cameraSessionController.sessionDelegate = self
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        cameraSessionController.startCamera()
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

        cameraSessionController.teardownCamera()
    }


    /* Instance Methods
    ------------------------------------------*/

    @IBAction func toggleShader(sender: AnyObject) {
        openGLView.shouldShowShader(togglerSwitch.on)
    }

    func cameraSessionDidOutputSampleBuffer(sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!) {
        openGLView.updateUsingSampleBuffer(sampleBuffer)
    }

}
```

The OpenGLView.swift UIView Class code given below.

```
//
//  OpenGLView.swift
//  iOSSwiftOpenGLCamera
//
//  Created by Bradley Griffith on 7/1/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Bradley Griffith. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import CoreMedia
import Foundation
import QuartzCore
import OpenGLES
import GLKit
import AVFoundation


struct Vertex {
    var Position: (CFloat, CFloat, CFloat)
    var TexCoord: (CFloat, CFloat)
}

var Vertices: (Vertex, Vertex, Vertex, Vertex) = (
    Vertex(Position: (1, -1, 0) , TexCoord: (1, 1)),
    Vertex(Position: (1, 1, 0)  , TexCoord: (1, 0)),
    Vertex(Position: (-1, 1, 0) , TexCoord: (0, 0)),
    Vertex(Position: (-1, -1, 0), TexCoord: (0, 1))
)

var Indices: (GLubyte, GLubyte, GLubyte, GLubyte, GLubyte, GLubyte) = (
    0, 1, 2,
    2, 3, 0
)


class OpenGLView: UIView {

    var eaglLayer: CAEAGLLayer!
    var context: EAGLContext!
    var colorRenderBuffer: GLuint = GLuint()
    var positionSlot: GLuint = GLuint()
    var texCoordSlot: GLuint = GLuint()
    var textureUniform: GLuint = GLuint()
    var timeUniform: GLuint = GLuint()
    var showShaderBoolUniform: GLuint = GLuint()
    var indexBuffer: GLuint = GLuint()
    var vertexBuffer: GLuint = GLuint()
    var unmanagedVideoTexture: Unmanaged<CVOpenGLESTexture>?
    var videoTexture: CVOpenGLESTextureRef?
    var videoTextureID: GLuint?
    var unmanagedCoreVideoTextureCache: Unmanaged<CVOpenGLESTextureCache>?
    var coreVideoTextureCache: CVOpenGLESTextureCacheRef?

    var textureWidth: UInt?
    var textureHeight: UInt?

    var time: GLfloat = 0.0
    var showShader: GLfloat = 1.0

    var frameTimestamp: Double = 0.0

    /* Class Methods
    ------------------------------------------*/

    override class func layerClass() -> AnyClass {
        // In order for our view to display OpenGL content, we need to set it's
        //   default layer to be a CAEAGLayer
        return CAEAGLLayer.self
    }


    /* Lifecycle
    ------------------------------------------*/

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        setupLayer()
        setupContext()
        setupRenderBuffer()
        setupFrameBuffer()
        compileShaders()
        setupVBOs()
        setupDisplayLink()

        self.contentScaleFactor =  UIScreen.mainScreen().scale
    }


    /* Setup Methods
    ------------------------------------------*/

    func setupLayer() {
        // CALayer's are, by default, non-opaque, which is 'bad for performance with OpenGL',
        //   so let's set our CAEAGLLayer layer to be opaque.
        eaglLayer = layer as CAEAGLLayer
        eaglLayer.opaque = true

    }

    func setupContext() {

        // Just like with CoreGraphics, in order to do much with OpenGL, we need a context.     //   Here we create a new context with the version of the rendering API we want and
        //   tells OpenGL that when we draw, we want to do so within this context.
        let api: EAGLRenderingAPI = EAGLRenderingAPI.OpenGLES2
        context = EAGLContext(API: api)

        if let contextValue = self.context as EAGLContext?
        {
            let err: CVReturn = CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, nil, contextValue, nil, &unmanagedCoreVideoTextureCache)
            coreVideoTextureCache = unmanagedCoreVideoTextureCache!.takeUnretainedValue()
        }
        else
        {
            println("Failed to initialize OpenGLES 2.0 context!")
            exit(1)

        }


    }

    func setupRenderBuffer() {
        // A render buffer is an OpenGL objec that stores the rendered image to present to the screen.
        //   OpenGL will create a unique identifier for a render buffer and store it in a GLuint.
        //   So we call the glGenRenderbuffers function and pass it a reference to our colorRenderBuffer.
        glGenRenderbuffers(1, &colorRenderBuffer)
        // Then we tell OpenGL that whenever we refer to GL_RENDERBUFFER, it should treat that as our colorRenderBuffer.
        glBindRenderbuffer( (GLenum) (GL_RENDERBUFFER.value), colorRenderBuffer)
        // Finally, we tell our context that the render buffer for our layer is our colorRenderBuffer.
        context.renderbufferStorage(Int(GL_RENDERBUFFER), fromDrawable:eaglLayer)
    }

    func setupFrameBuffer() {
        // A frame buffer is an OpenGL object for storage of a render buffer... amongst other things (tm).
        //   OpenGL will create a unique identifier for a frame vuffer and store it in a GLuint. So we
        //   make a GLuint and pass it to the glGenFramebuffers function to keep this identifier.
        var frameBuffer: GLuint = GLuint()
        glGenFramebuffers(1, &frameBuffer)
        // Then we tell OpenGL that whenever we refer to GL_FRAMEBUFFER, it should treat that as our frameBuffer.
        glBindFramebuffer( (GLenum) (GL_FRAMEBUFFER.value), frameBuffer)
        // Finally we tell the frame buffer that it's GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 is our colorRenderBuffer. Oh.
        glFramebufferRenderbuffer( (GLenum) (GL_FRAMEBUFFER.value), (GLenum) (GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0.value), (GLenum) (GL_RENDERBUFFER.value), colorRenderBuffer)
    }

    func compileShader(shaderName: NSString, shaderType: GLenum) -> GLuint {

        // Get NSString with contents of our shader file.
        let shaderPath: NSString = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(shaderName, ofType: "glsl")!

        var shaderString: NSString? = NSString.stringWithContentsOfFile(shaderPath, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)

        let shaderHandle: GLuint = glCreateShader(shaderType)

        if let shaderStringValue = shaderString as NSString?
        {
            // Tell OpenGL to create an OpenGL object to represent the shader, indicating if it's a vertex or a fragment shader.

            // Conver shader string to CString and call glShaderSource to give OpenGL the source for the shader.
            var shaderStringUTF8  = shaderStringValue.UTF8String
            var shaderStringLength: GLint = GLint.convertFromIntegerLiteral(Int32(shaderStringValue.length))
            glShaderSource(shaderHandle, 1, &shaderStringUTF8, &shaderStringLength)

            // Tell OpenGL to compile the shader.
            glCompileShader(shaderHandle)

            // But compiling can fail! If we have errors in our GLSL code, we can here and output any errors.
            var compileSuccess: GLint = GLint()
            glGetShaderiv(shaderHandle, (GLenum) (GL_COMPILE_STATUS.value), &compileSuccess)
            if (compileSuccess == GL_FALSE) {
                var value: GLint = 0
                glGetShaderiv(shaderHandle, GLenum(GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH), &value)
                var infoLog: [GLchar] = [GLchar](count: Int(value), repeatedValue: 0)
                var infoLogLength: GLsizei = 0
                glGetShaderInfoLog(shaderHandle, value, &infoLogLength, &infoLog)
                var messageString = NSString(bytes: infoLog, length: Int(infoLogLength), encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding)

                println("Failed to compile shader!")
                println(messageString)

                exit(1);
            }

        }
        else
        {
            println("Failed to set contents shader of shader file!")

        }


        return shaderHandle
    }

    func compileShaders() {

        // Compile our vertex and fragment shaders.
        let vertexShader: GLuint = compileShader("SimpleVertex", shaderType: (GLenum) (GL_VERTEX_SHADER.value))
        let fragmentShader: GLuint = compileShader("SimpleFragment", shaderType: (GLenum) (GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER.value))

        // Call glCreateProgram, glAttachShader, and glLinkProgram to link the vertex and fragment shaders into a complete program.
        var programHandle: GLuint = glCreateProgram()
        glAttachShader(programHandle, vertexShader)
        glAttachShader(programHandle, fragmentShader)
        glLinkProgram(programHandle)

        // Check for any errors.
        var linkSuccess: GLint = GLint()
        glGetProgramiv(programHandle, (GLenum) (GL_LINK_STATUS.value), &linkSuccess)
        if (linkSuccess == GL_FALSE) {
            println("Failed to create shader program!")
            // TODO: Actually output the error that we can get from the glGetProgramInfoLog function.
            exit(1);
        }

        // Call glUseProgram to tell OpenGL to actually use this program when given vertex info.
        glUseProgram(programHandle)

        // Finally, call glGetAttribLocation to get a pointer to the input values for the vertex shader, so we
        //  can set them in code. Also call glEnableVertexAttribArray to enable use of these arrays (they are disabled by default).
        positionSlot = (GLuint) (glGetAttribLocation(programHandle, "Position").value)
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(positionSlot)

        texCoordSlot = (GLuint) (glGetAttribLocation(programHandle, "TexCoordIn").value)
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(texCoordSlot);

        textureUniform = (GLuint) (glGetUniformLocation(programHandle, "Texture").value)

        timeUniform = (GLuint) (glGetUniformLocation(programHandle, "time").value)

        showShaderBoolUniform = (GLuint) (glGetUniformLocation(programHandle, "showShader").value)
    }

    // Setup Vertex Buffer Objects
    func setupVBOs() {
        glGenBuffers(1, &vertexBuffer)
        glBindBuffer( (GLenum) (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER.value), vertexBuffer)
        glBufferData( (GLuint) (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER.value), Int(sizeofValue(Vertices)), &Vertices, (GLenum) (GL_STATIC_DRAW.value))

        glGenBuffers(1, &indexBuffer)
        glBindBuffer( (GLenum) (GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER.value), indexBuffer)
        glBufferData( (GLenum) (GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER.value), Int(sizeofValue(Indices)), &Indices, (GLenum) (GL_STATIC_DRAW.value))
    }

    func setupDisplayLink() {
        let displayLink: CADisplayLink = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: "render:")
        displayLink.addToRunLoop(NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop(), forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)
    }


    /* Helper Methods
    ------------------------------------------*/

//  func getTextureFromImageWithName(fileName: NSString) -> GLuint {
//      
//      var spriteImage: CGImageRef? = UIImage(named: fileName).CGImage
//      
//        var texName: GLuint = GLuint()
//
//      if let spriteImageValue = spriteImage  as CGImageRef?
//        {
//            let width: UInt = CGImageGetWidth(spriteImageValue)
//            let height: UInt = CGImageGetHeight(spriteImageValue)
//            
//            let spriteData = UnsafePointer<GLubyte>(calloc(UInt(CGFloat(width) * CGFloat(height) * 4), sizeof((GLubyte).value)
//            
//            let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo.fromRaw(CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedLast.toRaw())!
//            let spriteContext: CGContextRef = CGBitmapContextCreate(spriteData, width, height, 8, width*4, CGImageGetColorSpace(spriteImageValue), bitmapInfo)
//            
//            CGContextDrawImage(spriteContext, CGRectMake(0, 0, CGFloat(width) , CGFloat(height)), spriteImageValue)
//            CGContextRelease(spriteContext)
//            
//            glGenTextures(1, &texName)
//            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D.asUnsigned(), texName)
//            
//            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D.asUnsigned(), GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER.asUnsigned(), GL_NEAREST)
//            glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D.asUnsigned(), 0, GL_RGBA, GLsizei(width), GLsizei(height), 0, GL_RGBA.asUnsigned(), UInt32(GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE), spriteData)
//            
//            free(spriteData)
//
//      }
//        else
//        {
//            println("Failed to load image!")
//            exit(1)
//            
//        }
//      
//              return texName
//  }

    func cleanupVideoTextures()
    {
        if let videoTextureValue  = videoTexture as CVOpenGLESTextureRef?  {
            videoTexture = nil
        }
        CVOpenGLESTextureCacheFlush(coreVideoTextureCache, 0)
    }

    func getTextureFromSampleBuffer(sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!) -> GLuint {
        cleanupVideoTextures()

        var unmanagedImageBuffer: CVImageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)
        var imageBuffer = unmanagedImageBuffer
        var opaqueImageBuffer = unmanagedImageBuffer

        var cameraFrame: CVPixelBuffer = opaqueImageBuffer
        textureWidth = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(cameraFrame)
        textureHeight = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(cameraFrame)

        CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(cameraFrame, 0)

        var err: CVReturn = CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(
                                        kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                        coreVideoTextureCache,
                                        imageBuffer,
                                        nil,
                                        (GLenum) (GL_TEXTURE_2D.value),
                                        GL_RGBA,
                                        GLsizei(textureWidth!),
                                        GLsizei(textureHeight!),
                                        (GLenum) (GL_BGRA.value),
                                        UInt32(GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE),
                                        0,
                                        &unmanagedVideoTexture
                                    )

        videoTexture = unmanagedVideoTexture!.takeUnretainedValue()

        var textureID: GLuint = GLuint()
        textureID = CVOpenGLESTextureGetName(videoTexture);
        glBindTexture( (GLenum) (GL_TEXTURE_2D.value), textureID);

        glTexParameteri( (GLenum) (GL_TEXTURE_2D.value), (GLenum) (GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER.value), GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri((GLenum) (GL_TEXTURE_2D.value), (GLenum) (GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER.value), GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri( (GLenum) (GL_TEXTURE_2D.value), (GLenum)(GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S.value), GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glTexParameteri( (GLenum) (GL_TEXTURE_2D.value), (GLenum) (GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T.value), GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);


        CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(cameraFrame, 0)


        return textureID
    }

    func updateUsingSampleBuffer(sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            self.videoTextureID = self.getTextureFromSampleBuffer(sampleBuffer)
        });
    }

    func shouldShowShader(show: Bool) {
        showShader = show ? 1.0 : 0.0
    }

    func render(displayLink: CADisplayLink) {

        if let textureWidthValue = textureWidth as UInt?
        {
            if let textureHeightValue = textureHeight as UInt?
            {
                var ratio = CGFloat(frame.size.height) / CGFloat(textureHeightValue)
                glViewport(0, 0, GLint(CGFloat(textureWidthValue) * ratio), GLint(CGFloat(textureHeightValue) * ratio))
            }

        }
        else
        {

            glViewport(0, 0, GLint(self.frame.size.width), GLint(self.frame.size.height))
        }

        let positionSlotFirstComponent = UnsafePointer<Int>(bitPattern: 0)
        glVertexAttribPointer(positionSlot, 3 as GLint, (GLenum) (GL_FLOAT.value), GLboolean.convertFromIntegerLiteral(UInt8(GL_FALSE)), Int32(sizeof(Vertex)), positionSlotFirstComponent)

        let texCoordFirstComponent = UnsafePointer<Int>(bitPattern: sizeof(Float) * 3)
        glVertexAttribPointer(texCoordSlot, 2, (GLenum) (GL_FLOAT.value), GLboolean.convertFromIntegerLiteral(UInt8(GL_FALSE)), Int32(sizeof(Vertex)), texCoordFirstComponent)
        glActiveTexture(UInt32(GL_TEXTURE0))
        if let videoTextureIDValue = videoTextureID as GLuint?  {
            glBindTexture( (GLenum) (GL_TEXTURE_2D.value), videoTextureIDValue)
            glUniform1i( (GLint) (textureUniform.value), 0)
        }

        // Incriment and pass time to shader. This is experimental, be sure to fully test any use of this variable.
        time += Float(displayLink.duration)
        glUniform1f( (GLint) (timeUniform.value), time)

        glUniform1f( (GLint) (showShaderBoolUniform.value), showShader)

        let vertextBufferOffset = UnsafePointer<Int>(bitPattern: 0)
        glDrawElements( (GLenum) (GL_TRIANGLES.value), Int32(GLfloat(sizeofValue(Indices)) / GLfloat(sizeofValue(Indices.0))), (GLenum) (GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE.value), vertextBufferOffset)

        context.presentRenderbuffer(Int(GL_RENDERBUFFER))
    }
}
```

I use AVFoundation to capture the image and pass the buffer to the OpenGLView.swift UIView class. i have files in the format of "glsl". When i run the program i get the error.

" Failed to compile shader! ". I don't know why if anybody know something about this, please let me know. Thank You.

I was using someother shader codes, when i go this error i tried some simple shading code. that given below.

Fragment Shader (.fsh)

```
void main(void) {
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1.9, 1.9, 0.7, 1.3);
}
```

Vertex Shader (.vsh).

```
attribute vec2 aPosition;

void main(void) {
    gl_Position = vec4(aPosition, 0., 1.);
}
```

Comment: Can you not get the shader compile log? Most likely there is a bug in the shader itself if it can not be compiled...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
positionSlot = (GLuint) (glGetAttribLocation(programHandle, "Position").value)
glEnableVertexAttribArray(positionSlot)

texCoordSlot = (GLuint) (glGetAttribLocation(programHandle, "TexCoordIn").value)
glEnableVertexAttribArray(texCoordSlot);

textureUniform = (GLuint) (glGetUniformLocation(programHandle, "Texture").value)
timeUniform = (GLuint) (glGetUniformLocation(programHandle, "time").value)

showShaderBoolUniform = (GLuint) (glGetUniformLocation(programHandle, "showShader").value)
```

gets attributes that don't exist in the compiled shaders. Changing:

```
positionSlot = (GLuint) (glGetAttribLocation(programHandle, "Position").value)
glEnableVertexAttribArray(positionSlot)
```

to

```
positionSlot = (GLuint) (glGetAttribLocation(programHandle, "aPosition").value)
glEnableVertexAttribArray(positionSlot)
```

(note "Position" -> "aPosition") to reflect the attribute name in

```
attribute vec2 aPosition;
void main(void) {
    gl_Position = vec4(aPosition, 0., 1.);
}
```